# Fastest way to output frames between 34885 and 34891 as images in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to extract frames between a certain number as images

Currently I am doing it like this

```
ffmpeg 
-i input.mp4 
-vf select='eq(n\,34885)+eq(n\,34886)+eq(n\,34887)+eq(n\,34888)+eq(n\,34889)+eq(n\,34890)+eq(n\,34891)' 
-vsync 0 output_frames_%d.png
```

Not only this the command above very cumbersome but also takes a lot of time to run, is there an easier and faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
 ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select='between(n\,34885\,34891)'" -vsync 0 -start_number 34885 out-%02d.png
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf select='between(n\,34885\,34891)' -vsync passthrough -frames 7 frame_%d.png
```

It's less cumbersome and stops once it has hit the target number of frames (7).